# How to resize images to fit a fixed size inside a CardView in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-linearlayout, android-cardview

I have several CardViews with an ImageView to the left of each one.

Each ImageView has a layout_weight to make it fit the same width for every CardView and a fixed height (in this case, 80dp).

When the images are horizontal they look OK, like **1**, **2** and **5**. But when those are vertical they don't fit the same like **3** and **4**.

[image]

I have tried: Declaring layout_weight directly on the ImageViews / Moving the ImageViews inside LinearLayout and declaring layout_weight on it (actual code) / Buttons instead of ImageViews / Using adjustViewBounds and every scaleType. None of this worked.

This is my actual code for each CardView, I will appreciate any help! Thank you in advance :)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardElevation="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="7dp">

                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/cardview_inner_linearlayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/imageview_linearlayout"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:layout_weight="7">

                        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageview"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:src="@drawable/halloween1" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/whitearea_linearlayout"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                         // White area to the right of the image

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly advise to start using percents instead of weight
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html

For now you can use the following layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    app:cardElevation="3dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/cardview_inner_linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/imageview_linearlayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/halloween1"/> 

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/whitearea_linearlayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the scale type of the image

Answer (score 0):

Use the `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` in ImageView attributes.